# How to refresh the listview of graphs with dynamic data using androidplot

Tags: java, android, android-listview, androidplot

I am using a Listview of two graphs plotted using androidplot library. I don't know how to constantly update the listview whenever I have new incoming data.

I have a method which receives random data from a device continuously. I have to update the two graphs with this new data. I use a custom view adapter built from Array adapter as found below.

```
class MyViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<View> {
    public MyViewAdapter(Context context, int resId, List<View> views) {
        super(context, resId, views);
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int pos, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inf = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View v = convertView;
        if (v == null) {
            v = inf.inflate(R.layout.listview_example_item, parent, false);
        }

        p = (XYPlot) v.findViewById(R.id.xyplot);

        Random generator = new Random();
        p.setTitle("plot" + pos);

        for (int k = 0; k < NUM_SERIES_PER_PLOT; k++) {

            double rl = Math.random();
            double gl = Math.random();
            double bl = Math.random();

            double rp = Math.random();
            double gp = Math.random();
            double bp = Math.random();
            if(setArrayValues != null){
            if(pos == 0) {
                XYSeries series = new SimpleXYSeries(setArrayValues.getSeries1Numbers(), SimpleXYSeries.ArrayFormat.Y_VALS_ONLY, "RPM");
                //XYSeries series = new SimpleXYSeries(nums, SimpleXYSeries.ArrayFormat.Y_VALS_ONLY, "RPM");
                p.addSeries(series, new LineAndPointFormatter(
                        Color.rgb(new Double(rl * 255).intValue(), new Double(gl * 255).intValue(), new Double(bl * 255).intValue()),
                        Color.rgb(new Double(rp * 255).intValue(), new Double(gp * 255).intValue(), new Double(bp * 255).intValue()),
                        null, null));
            }
            else{
                XYSeries series = new SimpleXYSeries(setArrayValues.getSeries2Numbers(), SimpleXYSeries.ArrayFormat.Y_VALS_ONLY, "SPEED");
                //XYSeries series = new SimpleXYSeries(nums, SimpleXYSeries.ArrayFormat.Y_VALS_ONLY, "SPEED");
                p.addSeries(series, new LineAndPointFormatter(
                        Color.rgb(new Double(rl * 255).intValue(), new Double(gl * 255).intValue(), new Double(bl * 255).intValue()),
                        Color.rgb(new Double(rp * 255).intValue(), new Double(gp * 255).intValue(), new Double(bp * 255).intValue()),
                        null, null));
            }
        }
        }
        p.redraw();



        return v;
    }
}
```

The below method receives data from a device and updates relevant Arraylists.

```
   public void receivePackage() throws SocketException {

    new Thread() {

        byte[] packet = new byte[64];
        DatagramPacket data = new DatagramPacket(packet,
                packet.length);
        DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(null);

        JSONObject json;

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                isRunning = true;
                socket.setReuseAddress(true);
                socket.bind(new InetSocketAddress(50009));
            } catch (SocketException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {

                while (isRunning) {

                    socket.receive(data);

                    final String string = new String(
                            data.getData(), 0,
                            data.getLength(), "UTF-8");

                    json = new JSONObject(string);

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            try {                                   
                                int wiper = json.getInt("wiper");
                                int speed = json.getInt("speed");
                                speed = speed + 2000;

                                setArrayValues.addValues(wiper,speed);
                                lv.invalidateViews();

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            socket.close(); // keep this out of while
        }
    }.start();
}
```

Actually I cannot plot the data points in the graph. I have used

```
setArrayValues.addValues(wiper,speed);
```

I have a separate helper class which sets the values to two different ArrayLists which I use in the line

```
    XYSeries series = new SimpleXYSeries(setArrayValues.getSeries1Numbers(), SimpleXYSeries.ArrayFormat.Y_VALS_ONLY, "RPM");  

XYSeries series = new SimpleXYSeries(setArrayValues.getSeries2Numbers(), SimpleXYSeries.ArrayFormat.Y_VALS_ONLY, "RPM");
```

But the values are not displayed in the plot.  Can you suggest any solution for this.

Comment: look at notifyDataSetChanged method -> http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged()

Answer (score 0):

The notifyDatasetChanged will retrigger the getView for your visible views.
Be careful that you'll have to reset the graphs before setting the new data.
It's not gonna be efficient tho.
Why are you using a listView if you only have two graphs? A ScrollView with a linearlayout would be much easier to manage.

Comment: I have some problem in displaying the data points in the graph now. I have edited the question. Can you take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing all of your code, I would guess that one of the following is the case.

1) You never initialize setArrayValues, so that setArrayValues == null, and hence the series are never created.

2) You are not calling notifyDataSetChanged on your adapter. For instance, if you want the graphs to repeatedly update, then you need to call notifyDataSetChanged on your adapter, which will trigger a call to getView(), where you are creating the plots.

The problem seems to be outside of the code you have displayed. Something is not being done properly. Its hard to even tell if you actually set up an adapter. For instance, it seems like the easiest way to set up your code would be to have an ArrayAdapter, and then call notifyDataSetChanged. It seems like you are trying to accomplish the same thing by using lv.invalidateViews();, where I'm guessing that lv stands for ListView. If this is the case, then that is the problem... You need to have some type of adapter for the listView, and it seems like you don't have one. Try setting up an arrayAdapter, then in place of lv.invalidateViews();, use

myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();